# python: argument generated by a prior function error

Tags: python, json, dictionary

so this is probably very simple but it's confusing me.

I have a function that takes in a txt file in JSON form and sorts it in descending order of bandwidth. The function is:

```
def sort_guards_with_input(guards):
json_source = json.dumps(guards)
data = json.loads(str(json_source))
data['relays'].sort(key=lambda item: item['bandwidth'], reverse=True)
data = json.dumps(data)
return data

segundo = sort_guards_with_input("the original txt file")
```

..and this returns the sorted file of the form (lets call it TEXT):

```
{"relays": [{"nickname": "Snowden4ever pd7wih1gdUU8bLhWsvH6QHDWfs8", 
"bandwidth": 201000, "type": ["Fast", "Guard", "HSDir", "Named", "Running", 
"Stable", "V2Dir", "Valid"]},{"nickname": "rmblue jMdIu0VZYE+S2oeHShQBAHsdj80",
"bandwidth": 8, "type": ["Fast", "Guard", "HSDir", "Running", "Stable", "Unnamed", 
"V2Dir", "Valid"]}]}
```

Now I have a function that pulls out the banwidth and nickname and creates a list. The function is:

```
def get_sorted_names_bw(guards):
  sorted_guards_bw = list(entry['bandwidth'] for entry in guards["relays"])
  sorted_guards_names = list(d['nickname'] for d in guards["relays"])
  temps = [None]*(len(sorted_guards_bw)+len(sorted_guards_names))
  temps[::2] = sorted_guards_bw
  temps[1::2] = sorted_guards_names
  sorted_grds_w_names = [temps[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(temps), 2)]
  return sorted_grds_w_names
```

The problem is when I try and print the result of get_sorted_names_bw by doing:

```
print get_sorted_names_bw(segundo)
```

.. I get the error:

> sorted_guards_bw = list(entry['bandwidth'] for entry in guards["relays"])
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

But if i try and print the the result of get_sorted_names_bw with copy and pasting TEXT as the argument it returns a result (the wrong one because nicknames and bandwidths are mixed up, that's another problem I'll deal with myself, unless the reader is feeling very kind and wants to help with that too :) ). Namely:

```
[[201000, 'rmblue jMdIu0VZYE+S2oeHShQBAHsdj80'], [8, 'Snowden4ever pd7wih1gdUU8bLhWsvH6QHDWfs8']]
```

Why do I get an error when I try use an argument generated by a prior function but don't get an error when I just copy and paste the argument?

Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sort_guards_with_input` dumps the data to a JSON string and returns that string.  But `get_sorted_names_bw` assumes it is receiving the actual data (as a dict), not a string representation of it.  The easiest thing is probably to just have `sort_guards_with_input` return `data` without dumping it to JSON.  That is:

```
def sort_guards_with_input(guards):
    json_source = json.dumps(guards)
    data = json.loads(str(json_source))
    data['relays'].sort(key=lambda item: item['bandwidth'], reverse=True)
    return data
```

Comment: So this works but I added the dumps line because I didn't want my strings returned as unicode. Is there another solution? Or a simple way to convert from unicode?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want them as unicode?  Unicode is usually a better choice anyway.

Comment: For working with, no I don't have a reason so your solution works great. Thank you very much. But just out of interest is there an efficient way to encode an entire list of unicode strings in ascii or something else? Thanks

Comment: If you have a list of unicode objects you can do `[s.encode('utf8') for s in list_of_unicode]` to encode then as UTF8, or put in `'ascii'` or whatever to use a different encoding.  You can find more info about this by searching on this site and elsewhere.  If you have questions about that aspect about it it's probably better to ask a separate question, since it's tangential to this question.